# Get image URL from media library "insert from url"

Tags: media-library

I was trying to get the URL of the uploaded image via media uploader option **"Insert from URL"**

[image]

I use and below code, It works for just for **"Insert Media"**,

```
    var abc = wp.media.frames.abc = wp.media({
            frame:    'post',
            state:    'insert',
            library: { type: 'image' },
            editing:   false,
            multiple: false,
        });

        abc.on( 'insert', function() { 
            json = fn.state().get( 'selection' ).first().toJSON();
            console.log(json.title);
            console.log(json.url);
        });
```

How can I get the URL from tab **"Insert from URL"**, When user insert URL & click on **Add Image/Insert in Page**?

> Any suggestions. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Got the solution...!

Use `fn.state('embed'` insted of `fn.on( 'insert'` 
Or use **Both** of them `fn.state('embed'` & `fn.on( 'insert'`

```
fn.state('embed').on( 'select', function() {
    var state = fn.state(),
        type = state.get('type'),
        embed = state.props.toJSON();

    // SHOW JSON for embeded URL
    console.log('embed'+JSON.stringify(embed));
});
```